# [Error expected expression before '{' token

Tags: c, struct, initialization, c-strings, assignment-operator

Hello i'm a beginner in C and I don't know why
I'm getting this error on this line every time I try to compile

```
    CURRENT->name = {'L','O','U','D','A'};
```

Here is my whole code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
char name[15];
int age;
struct node *next;
}TEMPLATE;


int main()
{
    struct node *HEAD;      
    HEAD = (struct node*) malloc (sizeof(struct node)); 
    
    
    struct node *TAIL;
    TAIL = (struct node*) malloc (sizeof(struct node));
 
    
    struct node *CURRENT;
    CURRENT = (struct node*) malloc (sizeof(struct node));
    CURRENT->name = {'L','O','U','D','A'};
    CURRENT->age = 24;
    CURRENT->next = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `strcpy`, `strcpy(CURRENT->name, "LOUDA")`.

Comment: This syntax is only valid in an initilization of a variable. It cannot be used in an assigment.

Answer (score 0):

You may use a braced list only as an initializer of a declaration.

But this

```
CURRENT->name = {'L','O','U','D','A'};
```

is not a declaration but an expression statement

You could write

```
#include <string.h>

//...

strcpy( CURRENT->name, "LOUDA" );
```

Pay attention to that the declaration of the global variable TEMPLATE

```
struct node{
char name[15];
int age;
struct node *next;
}TEMPLATE;
```

does not make a sense. So declare the structure

```
struct node{
char name[15];
int age;
struct node *next;
};
```

and allocates nodes dynamically as in this statement

```
 HEAD = (struct node*) malloc (sizeof(struct node))
```